# How can I add planets to an existing sector?

Tags: stellaris

I've started playing Stellaris for the first time and have integrated a few factions into my quickly growing empire. I've established sectors where there are colonies in close proximity, but any planets that more than a few hyperlane jumps away remain as frontier worlds.

These frontier worlds are situated right next to my sector's capital planet but due to hyperlane travel is *technically* four jumps away. Due to it's superficial proximity I'd like to add this planet to my existing sector, but I only see options to declare it as a new sector.

Is there a way to add distant planets to existing sectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old versions of Stellaris allowed us to add/remove systems to/from a sector.  This is no longer a thing.

When a Sector is created it will extend 4 hyperlane hops from the sector capital.  Each time I've changed a sector's capital that radius seems to decrease.
My general technique is to identify which world I want to be the new capital, delete the sector entirely, then create it anew.

Honestly, the biggest cost of a new sector is the Governor, and having a governor training in a small sector for when the guy running the larger sector passes or becomes corrupt is a *good* thing.